# Extended GCD of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Say $H(x),F(x),G(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]$ with degrees $h$, $f$ and $g$ respectively. Let:

$1)$ $f,g<h<f+g$

$2)$ $gcd(F(x),G(x))=1$.

$$\mbox{Extended GCD }\implies\exists A(x),B(x)\in\Bbb Q[x]:F(x)A(x) + G(x)B(x) = H(x).$$ $$\mbox{Let }deg(A(x))=a\mbox{ and }deg(B(x))=b.$$

Is $h>a+b$?

Is $a=h-f$ and $b=h-g$ always possible?

Are there more than one $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ with degrees $h-f$ and $h-g$ respectively?

Comment: Your premise is not actually true: $\gcd(2, x) = 1$, but you cannot find integer polynomials such that $2a(x) + xb(x) = 1$.

Comment: oic I thought extended gcd holds for $\Bbb Z[x]$. Is it not true?

Comment: The ring of integer polynomials has problems with GCDs, as my example demonstrates. They behave reasonably in the ring of polynomials over the *rationals*, though.

Comment: ohhh. so $\Bbb Z[x]$ is not a euclidean domain?

Comment: just looking up wiki.. it is missing Z[x] in the examples http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Examples

Comment: So it holds in instead of $\Bbb Z[x]$ we had $\Bbb Q[x]$?

Comment: Right. A polynomial ring over any *field* is fine too. But when you have polynomials over rings, the primes in the ring and the irreducible polynomials don't play nicely together in terms of extended GCDs. (aside: I haven't thought about your conjecture yet)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $h = g \geq f$ and $h(x) = 1 + g(x)$.

If we have

$$ a(x) f(x) + b(x) g(x) = h(X) $$

then we also have

$$ a(x) f(x) + (b(x) - 1) g(x) = 1 $$

If we require $a < g$ and $b < f$, then there is only one possibility for the values of $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, and we can find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ so that  we must have $a = g-1$ and $b = f-1$.

In particular, we cannot suppose that we can find $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ so that $a \leq h-f$ and $b=0$ as you suppose.

I'm fairly certain that if you require $h \geq f+g$, then your conjecture holds true. You can probably shave 1 or 2 off of that lower bound, but my initial thoughts are that you can't do better than that if you want actual guarantees.

Comment: What happens if $h<f+g$?